# How to apply a transition to qml ListView.footer?

Tags: listview, qml

I've added transitions for add, remove and displaced to my QML `ListView` and they work as expected, except for the footer.

The footer just jumps to the destination position, while delegate items are still being animated. So the question stands: How do I apply a transition to QML `ListView.footer`? Is this even possible?

Here's some example code. The commented lines are things I've tried but didn't work.

```js
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow { 
    visible: true; width: 640; height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "List"
            MenuItem { text: "Add Peach"; onTriggered: fruitModel2.append({"name":"Peach", "cost":5.00}) }
            MenuItem { text: "Clear Fruits"; onTriggered: fruitModel2.clear() }
            MenuItem { text: "Remove Peach"; onTriggered: fruitModel2.remove(2) }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: fruitModel2
        ListElement { name: "Apple"; cost: 2.45 }
        ListElement { name: "Orange"; cost: 3.25 }
        ListElement { name: "Banana"; cost: 1.95 }
    }

    ListView {
        id: theList
        anchors.fill: parent; model: fruitModel2; spacing: 5
        onHeightChanged: console.debug("heigt:", height)
        // Behavior on height { NumberAnimation {duration: 1000} }
        // Behavior on contentHeight { NumberAnimation {duration: 1000} }

        delegate: Row {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Text { text: "Fruit: " + name }
            Text { text: "Cost: $" + cost }
        }
        add: Transition {
            // ParallelAnimation {
                // NumberAnimation { property: "y"; duration: 1000}
            NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1; duration: 1000}
            // }
        }
        displaced: Transition { NumberAnimation { property: "y"; duration: 1000} }
        remove: Transition { NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 1; to: 0; duration: 1000} }

        footer: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 40
            color: "darkred"
            // Behavior on y { NumberAnimation {duration: 1000} }
        }
    }
}
```